# Unable to recover time varying AR1 parameter from State Space model

Tags: r, time-series, state-space-models, dlm

I am trying to do a Time varying parameters regression. The equation is as follows:

$y_t = a + b_t * x_{1t} + \epsilon_t$

Here a is fixed while $b_t$ is AR1.

My state space equations are :

There are 3 state variables $a, b_t, b_{mean}$  where $a$ is fixed and $b_t$ is mean reverting with AR1 parameter say $\phi$ and a mean of $b_{mean}$

Hence my evolution equation is:

$ \theta_t = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b_t \\ b_{mean} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 &\phi &1-\phi \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} (=GG)\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b_{t-1} \\ b_{mean} \end{bmatrix} (=\theta_{t-1} )+ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \epsilon_b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

My measurement equation is :
$y_t = FF * \theta_t + \epsilon_t$

where $FF = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_{1t} & 0  \end{bmatrix} $ hence my FF is time varying.

So in the language of dlm, I write my $FF = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &  0 \end{bmatrix}$
and my $JFF = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $

My code is as follows:

```
library(dlm)

parm_rest<- function(parm){
# AR1 Parameter.
parm[1]<- exp(parm[1])/( 1 + exp(parm[1]))

# Variance for y - parm[2]
# Variance for residuals of b_t

parm[2:3]<- exp(parm[2:3])

parm   
}


build_ssm_ar1 <- function(parm,X.mat) {
parm <- parm_rest(parm)

FF = matrix(c(1,0,0), nrow = 1,ncol=3)
JFF = matrix(c(0,1,0),nrow = 1, ncol=3)
r1 <- c(1,0,0)
r2 <- c(0,parm[1],1-parm[1])
r3 <- c(0,0,1)
GG<- rbind(r1,r2,r3)
V= parm[2]
W = diag(c(0,parm[3],0))    
dlm(FF= FF,V = V,JFF= JFF,GG = GG,W=W,m0 = c(0,0,0),C0=diag(c(100,100,100)),X= X.mat)
}

x1<- rnorm(1000)

b<- arima.sim(list(order= c(1,0,0),ar=.5),n=1000,
               sd = sqrt(.7)) + 200

y <- 3 + b*x1 + rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=1)

X.mat = x1

start.vals <- c(0,0,0)

TVP.mle = dlmMLE(y=y, parm=start.vals, X.mat = X.mat , build=build_ssm_ar1, hessian=T)

p1 <- parm_rest(TVP.mle$par)
p1


library(numDeriv)
jac <- jacobian(func = parm_rest,x = TVP.mle$par)
var = jac %*% solve(TVP.mle$hessian) %*% t(jac)
p1.sd <- sqrt(diag(var))
p1.sd

> p1
[1] 0.01434233 1.04832213 0.86076821
> p1.sd
[1] 0.01119914 0.07585144 0.11378615
```

My problem is that the first result of p1 should be .5 ( the AR1 parameter) Can someone tell me why I don't have this even accounting for the standard errors ?

The second / third result of p1 should be 1 and .7
They seem ok since  p1 +/- 2 *p1.sd covers them. Am I right as far as this is concerned?